# Scrolling off screen bitmap, on SurfaceView, down one row does not work

Tags: java, android, bitmap, scroll, surfaceview

Scrolling off screen bitmap, on SurfaceView, down one row does not work.

Try example code below to prove something seems broken in Android Java graphics bitmap system, or (more likely) there is something about this I do not understand, when scrolling an off screen bitmap down and drawing on on-screen SurfaceView canvas using drawBitmap.

Run code once and see how it smears the stroke only circle down the page like the circle was filled.

Then change the Y offset from 1 to - 1 and rerun the code and it scrolls up one line fine (hard to see as it's not animated).

```
package com.example.SurfaceViewTest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class SurfaceViewTest extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
private int intSurfaceWidth, intSurfaceHeight;

Bitmap bmpOffScreen;
Canvas cnvOffScreen = new Canvas();
Canvas c = new Canvas();

private static Paint paint = new Paint();

private static final String TAG = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) this.findViewById(R.id.Surface);
    mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
    mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

    paint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    intSurfaceWidth = width;
    intSurfaceHeight = height;

    bmpOffScreen = Bitmap.createBitmap(intSurfaceWidth, intSurfaceHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    cnvOffScreen = new Canvas(bmpOffScreen);

    cnvOffScreen.drawCircle(intSurfaceWidth / 2, intSurfaceHeight / 2, 100, paint);

    c = null;
    c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);

    if (c == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Canvas bu-huu");
    } else {
        // Scroll off screen canvas and hopefully underlying bitmap bitmap
        Rect src = new Rect(0, 0, intSurfaceWidth, intSurfaceHeight);
        Rect dst = new Rect(0, 0, intSurfaceWidth, intSurfaceHeight);
        dst.offset(0, 1);
        cnvOffScreen.drawBitmap(bmpOffScreen, src, dst, null);

        // This produces exact same smear, but works fine scrolling up!?!
        cnvOffScreen.translate(0,1);
        cnvOffScreen.drawBitmap(bmpOffScreen, 0, 0, paint);

        c.drawBitmap(bmpOffScreen, 0, 0, paint);

        mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {}
}
```

Comment: Added a solution here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/22070/how-to-update-off-screen-bitmap-in-a-surfaceview-thread

Answer (score 2):

There is a drawBitmap function within canvas with the following signature:

```
public void drawBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, RectF dst, Paint paint);
```

You can make your dst the size of the canvas, and your src can be set up to be new

```
 Rect(0,offset,width,height+offset)
```

You can then increment offset every frame and get a smoothly scrolling bitmap in your view.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and figured out why this happened. It's due to a bit of negligence in android's translate function. Basically it's because the function ONLY works by copying pixels left-to-right per row from top-to-bottom, without checking which direction you're translating to. So going left and down, it works because it is copying existing pixels to 'old' pixels, but the other way around, you're copying pixels to pixels you want to copy later on.

The trick to solving this is to use the faster translate function in the right/down translation, but use a slower, bitmap copying way for the other directions. Or maybe find some way to override the translate function with one which does it correctly, but I haven''t figured out how to do that yet.

I have a little writeup here:
http://spiralcode.wordpress.com/2013/06/17/long-time-no-see-of-rivers-cartography-and-tiling/